# How to get parameters properties from a program in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dbms-scheduler

I have created a program with dbms_scheduler :

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM (
       program_name=>xxx ,
       program_type=>xxx,
       program_action=>xxx,
       number_of_arguments=>xxx ,
       enabled=>xxx ,
       comments=>xxx );
```

Can you please tell how can i get the arguments/parameters of a created program in Oracle or if you have any system table to suggest

PS : i already checked the table: ALL_ARGUMENTS (the program doesn't even figure in this table list but it figures in the table ALL_OBJECTS)

Thank u for helping !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for the view **dba_scheduler_program_args**

Comment: Thank you ! i just changed the "dba" by "user" to get "user_scheduler_program_args" because "dba_scheduler_program_args" returns the error : ORA-00942: table or view does not exist